# How do I get apache HTTP server to log the SSL Protocol for requests

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I am planning on disabling TLSV1 on an apache 2.4 server running on Ubuntu 14.04. Before doing this I thought it would be good to analyse how many users this would impact. I've read through the apache log documentation, which should allow me to log environment variables.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html

I have a RewriteRule I set up redirect users with TLSV1 which works fine, this rule looks like this.

```
    RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_PROTOCOL}  ^TLSv1$
    RewriteRule ^/test* /bad-ssl.html [L]
```

Which works perfectly. However I cannot get the log module to write SSl environment variables.

```
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl.log "%a \"%{SSL_PROTOCOL}e\" \"%{SSL:SSL_PROTOCOL}e\" \"%{evn:SSL_PROTOCOL}e\""
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable SSL_PROTOCOL (and all other mod_ssl variables) is technically not an environment variable, therefore

```
"%{VARNAME}e"
```

won't work.

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html (Section **Custom Log Formats**) you have to use the syntax:

```
"%{VARNAME}x"
```

for SSL variables.
To modify your config, it should read:

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl.log "%a \"%{SSL_PROTOCOL}x\""
```

*I assume SSL:SSL_PROTOCOL and evn:SSL_PROTOCOL were just attempts to achieve the same.*

Comment: Perfect many thanks. You're correct about my attempts with env: etc...